# ContextMenu.SourceControl property doesn't exists

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a WPF .NET 4.8 Exe application.I placed an TreeView control and made a void that is firing when window is loaded.This void adds all the sub directories and all of the files in all the sub directories and adds them to TreeView as TreeViewItem, and when they are creating their ContextMenu property is binding to a premade ContextMenu control.It also binds a click event to the MenuItems that ones ContextMenu contains.
I scripted the click event's void as RoutedEventArgs and wrote the code below (tried to access the TreeViewItem i created before).

I made some changes in my code to fix that problem but it did not work.

The code before:

```
            void showInExplorerFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("event triggered");
                MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
                //string tag = menuItem.Tag.ToString();
                ContextMenu parent = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;
                var baseParent = parent.SourceControl;

                Console.WriteLine("got success parent; ; ; ; ; ;" + menuItem.Name);
            }
```

The code after:

```
            void showInExplorerFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("event triggered");
                MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
                //string tag = menuItem.Tag.ToString();
                ContextMenu parent = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;
                TreeViewItem baseParent = (TreeViewItem)parent.SourceControl;

                Console.WriteLine("got success parent; ; ; ; ; ;" + menuItem.Name);
            }
```

And after theese changes i could not find any solution.
And the error code is here:

> CS1061    'ContextMenu' does not contain a definition of 'SourceControl' and no inaccessible extension method 'SourceControl' is available that accepts a first argument of type 'ContextMenu' (maybe you are missing a usage or annotation reference?)

I could not find any solution.If anyone could help me, i will be thankful.

Comment: But in Microsoft Dot Net Documentation it has ContextMenu.SourceControl, and i have seen it with my eyes in other code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.sourcecontrol?view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: Also WPF does not contain a control named ContextMenuStrip, i know like that

Comment: You are mixing WinForms and WPF. This doesn't work. You need to be careful when looking for code examples. Here try using this: `((sender as MenuItem).Parent as ContextMenu).PlacementTarget` see if this helps you. And WinForms is the devil lol

Comment: It just returned the source control, appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done here is mixed `WinForms` code sample with `WPF` application.
To solve your problem you need to change
`(TreeViewItem)parent.SourceControl;` which is WinForms as `SourceControl` is part of `ControlMenuStrip` which lives in `System.Windows.Forms.dll` [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), this is very important as `WPF` doesn't use that dll. It is a separate technology which uses different operating system components to render UI. For example WinForms is using GDI+ where `WPF` uses DirectX to render onto screen. Because of that you can't mix the 2 together as they are fundamentally different.
**Solution**
Use this `((sender as MenuItem).Parent as ContextMenu).PlacementTarget` as it is using `WPF` Controls and it is the equivalent of `SourceControl`. Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.placementtarget?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to MSDN that will show you, it is in a different assembly.
Hope this helps

Comment: This really helped too much, it been more than 1 month maybe but i think i forgot to thank you, if you haven't wrote this answer my project couldn't be more than a trash.

Comment: Aw, my pleasure. We are here to help